# Can't lock camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am having a problem with locking the camera in Unity while in pause menu. I am using UnityScript, and here is the code I have for the menu

```
#pragma strict

private var MenuShown:boolean=false;

function Start () {
    Cursor.visible = false; //set the cursor to be invisible
}

function Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) ){
        MenuShown=!MenuShown;
    }
}

function OnGUI() {
    if (MenuShown) {
        Time.timeScale=0;
        GameObject.Find("MainCamera").GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = false;
        GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = false;

        if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width*0.5-50,200-20,100,40),"Exit") ){
            ExitGame();
        }
        if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width*0.4-100,200-20,100,40),"Restart") ){
            Restart();
        }
        if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width*0.5-80,260,100,40),"Resume") ){
            Time.timeScale=1;
            GameObject.Find("MainCamera").GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = true;
            GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = true;
        }
    }
}

function ExitGame (){
    Application.Quit();         
}

function Restart(){
    Application.LoadLevel("HH_V1");
}
```

The names are correct (`Player`, `MainCamera`), I have checked. The Axes is set to Mouse X under `MouseLook` for `Player`, and as for `MainCamera`, it is set to Mouse Y. My Menu script is under Player.

Edit1:
I did not change any of the code from `MouseLook.cs`, but I will post it on here anyway:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/// MouseLook rotates the transform based on the mouse delta.
/// Minimum and Maximum values can be used to constrain the possible rotation

/// To make an FPS style character:
/// - Create a capsule.
/// - Add the MouseLook script to the capsule.
///   -> Set the mouse look to use LookX. (You want to only turn character but not tilt it)
/// - Add FPSInputController script to the capsule
///   -> A CharacterMotor and a CharacterController component will be automatically added.

/// - Create a camera. Make the camera a child of the capsule. Reset it's transform.
/// - Add a MouseLook script to the camera.
///   -> Set the mouse look to use LookY. (You want the camera to tilt up and down like a head. The character already turns.)
[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Look")]
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
    public float sensitivityX = 15F;
    public float sensitivityY = 15F;

    public float minimumX = -360F;
    public float maximumX = 360F;

    public float minimumY = -60F;
    public float maximumY = 60F;

    float rotationY = 0F;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
        {
            float rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;

            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
        }
    }

    void Start ()
    {
        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
    }
}
```

I think I know where the problem is, because I have another script which disables and enables the camera, and when I disable this script, Menu works fine.

Comment: your question is not clear. Is your camera moving and you want to stop it when menu is active?

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. Yes, the camera is still moving when the menu is active and I would like to stop it from moving.

Comment: I can't find anything directly wrong with the code you are showing. I think we would need more information before anyone could help you. Code for the MouseLook? And how the components are attached to Player and MainCamera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you must be moving your camera in update function. Then you should make MenuShown to a static variable and then call it the update function like this.

```
 function Update(){
        if (!classname.MenuShown) ){
            //you camera's transform update
        }
    }
```

You can post your script where you are translating camera, for better help.

Comment: I think I know where the problem is, I have another script which disables and enables the camera, when I disable this script, Menu works fine. Thank you guys.